# Easiest way to remove blackheads

Tags: cleaning, personal-care

What is the easiest fastest and not too expensive way too remove blackheads on the face? Especially the nose area.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a health issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a cheap and most effective way is to use Biore pore strips. It's something you buy, but you only need to use it a few times a month, so it will last for a long time. Some drug store brands pore strips works too, but I found those to be more skin irritating, so I think going with the original Biore brand is the best choice.

The homemade method is natural and wonderful, but it's not necessarily the cheapest method in terms of money and time for a very clean result. The ingredients you need for a homemade mask are not the cheapest thing out there.

I think it really just comes down to personal preference. :)

Answer (score 5):

First, shower with warm water and exfoliate your skin to remove the surface layers of skin keeping dirt and oil in there.

After showering and exfoliating, you can use a pimple extractor device - a little loop of metal you use to gently press down around the blackhead - to help squeeze the black stuff out.  (you can buy them online on Amazon etc easily).

To prevent it in the future, exfoliate daily with loofa or something else a little rough to help keep your pores clear.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get rid of blackhead on your nose is to give em a good ol' squeeze  Use one of two things;
- Tweezers
- Hair clip
[image]

The tweezers are the best option, you can tweeze the head off and remove the juicy under-layer quicker than you can say.."ahh, that's the spot".
As soon as you've finished, wash your face with lukewarm water and moisturise.
**Top tip:** Dab some toothpaste on spots or blackheads that are a little bigger than normal..this dries it out and ensures quicker healing.

Comment: The picture you have posted resembles more of hairpins than hair clips because hair clips come in varius sizes, shapes and materials whereas hairpins are usually metal and look like the picture you have posted.

Comment: That's why I've illustrated :-) I have heard a few names for such as "Kirby Grips"

Answer (score 2):

You can use mask from products you have at home to exfoliate your skin. There are different variants:

- cinnamon and honey
- egg-white
- oatmeal and yogurt
- clay mask (medical clay)

And you have to hydrate your skin to reduce fat production of the pores.

Comment: I like this answer, cause the other answer can bring scarring problems since they're too invasive on the skin, using an exfoliation procedure every three days is a nice solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to buy anything, I would add to Natalia's method.
Instead of buying an extractor or sorts, you can use the loop in a hairpin. Just push it in after you wash your face with warm water.

Other method to use both of you thumbs. Position your thumb nails around the blackhead and squeze and push.

Easiest way is to ask a family member. My sister does it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, Witch Hazel on a cotton pad and wipe the area until they disappear.

Also good for cleaning boo-boo's, although it's an astringent, it doesn't sting.  I spend $1.44 at the discount store for 1 pint, the same thing with the fancy label costs $4-$6.

Answer (score 2):

> Jojoba Oil as it is almost identical organically speaking to sebum, which is the natural oil produced by your skin. As well as being a great natural moisturizer it can also help with acne, Jojoba Oil penetrates into the skin without clogging pores and is suitable for all skin types it contains vitamin E and antioxidants which are great for fighting aging signs and moisturizing the skin. Studies on jojoba oil show that it has the ability to prevent skin from becoming too oily. This is due to the fact that putting jojoba oil on our skin can trick our cells into thinking they have produced enough oil. Remove any surface dirt from your skin, then put just a few drops of jojoba oil into your hand and rub it into your skin when you start to work jojoba oil into the skin, the oil penetrates into the pores. As jojoba closely resembles your skin's own oil, moisturizing with jojoba oil sends the message to your pores to stop overproducing the sebum that causing the oily skin.

Source : [Blackheads](http://www.fasthealthfitness.com/get-rid-deep-blackheads/)

Comment: This doesn't answer "how to remove blackheads" -- only "how to prevent blackheads and acne".  Different questions.

Answer (score 0):

Blackheads are mostly composed of oxidized melanin and they get worse when you scrub or squeeze.

**Inexpensive and Natural Treatment For Removing Blackheads**

- Natural extract based cleaners with no chemical ingredients are ideal
  for blackheads ridden skin.
- If there are any existing and underlying skin ailments as it can
  actually, aggravate any lesion- whether it is acne or blackheads.
- Home Remedies include the application of herbs like turmeric, lemon
  juice, tea tree oil and baking soda on the affected spots.However, you should try which of these remedies suit your skin better and do not go overboard in the application of this stuff.

[Prevent and Causes Of Blackheads](https://www.sehat.com/what-causes-blackheads)

[Source](https://www.sehat.com/what-causes-blackheads)